# Android TextView's setText() method

Tags: android, textview

I simply created a TextView and want to update its text using setText method

```
REMAINING_MINES.setText(Integer.toString(MINES_REMAINING));
```

where REMAINING_MINES is the TextView object, and MINES_REMAINING is an integer.
Obviously there's something wrong this line because nothing shows in the TextView; to make it worse, everything after this line won't get executed(it's inside an initializing function). Strangely i didn't see any compile errors or warnings, no runtime error was triggered either.
How do i correct this error?

Comment: You'll have to post more relevant code, not just the line. Post how do you get the `TextView`, when do you call the initializing method, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `valueOf` method from `String` Object as follows:

```
REMAINING_MINES.setText(String.valueOf(MINES_REMAINING));
```

For information, this method:

> Converts the specified integer to its string representation.
>   - **Parameters:** value the integer.
>   - **Returns:** the integer converted to a string.